# How to add post thumbnail dynamically using Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, post-thumbnails

In my wordpress website i am trying to add `post_thumbnail` to div `id="post-cont"` dynamically with jquery. After successfully adding `post_titel`.

**Jquery:**

```
<script>
$(function(){
 $('body').on('click', '.post-link', function(){
  var names = ['aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad'];
  $('#post-cont').fadeIn();
  var post_title = $(this).closest('div').find('a').text();
  var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
  var post_thumb = jQuery(this).append('<img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_url(get_post_thumbnail_id()); ?>" />');

  for (var i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
    if ($('#post-cont').find('input[name=' + names[i] + ']').length < 1) {
      $('#post-cont').append( '<div class="rows"><input name="' + names[i] + '" value="'+rel+'">'+post_thumb+' '+post_title+'-- <a href="#" class="close">REMOVE</a></input></div>' );   
  break;
 }
}
});
$('body').on('click', '.close', function() {
  $(this).closest('.rows').remove();
});

 $('.close').click(function(){
 $('#post-cont').fadeOut();
 });
});
</script>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php 
 if( have_posts() ):             
 while( have_posts() ): the_post();                 
   <?php the_post_thumbnail ('large', array('class' => 'img-responsive'));?>
   <button  class="post-link" rel="<?php the_ID(); ?>"> ADD </button>
endwhile;
endif; 
wp_reset_query();
?>

<div id="post-cont"> ...... </div>
```

I need to add both `post_title` and `post_thumb` with button  `class="post-link"` .

**How can i add post_thumbnail dynamically?**

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why do this using jQuery when WordPress can do it with PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

js (edit 4)

```
    $(function() {
        $('body').on('click', '.post-link', function() {
        // Jquery
        var ajax = {};
        ajax.id= $(this).attr('rel');
        var ajaxurl = '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
        jQuery.post(
        ajaxurl,
        {
        'action': 'get_img_post_and_title',
        'data': ajax
        },
        function(response){
        // add html
        if(response.success){
        $('#post-cont').append("<li>ID: "+response.data.post_id+" "+response.data.post_title+" <img src='"+response.data.post_thumb+"'/> --<a href='#' class='close'>X</a></li>");  
        }
        }
        );
    });
    });
```

php (edit 4)

```
     // php
    add_action("wp_ajax_get_img_post_and_title", "get_img_post_and_title");
         add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_get_img_post_and_title", "get_img_post_and_title");
        function get_img_post_and_title(){
         $return = array(
        'post_id' => $_POST['data']['id'],
'post_title' => get_the_title($_POST['data']['id']),
        'post_thumb' => wp_get_attachment_image_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($_POST['data']['id']))
        );
        wp_send_json_success($return);    
       }
```

index.php

```
    <?php 
 if( have_posts() ):             
 while( have_posts() ): the_post();                 
   <?php the_post_thumbnail ('large', array('class' => 'img-responsive'));?>
   <button  class="post-link" rel="<?php the_ID(); ?>"> ADD </button>
endwhile;
endif; 
wp_reset_query();
?>

<div id="post-cont"> ...... </div>
```

Comment: Hello @TrubinE i try but unable to work your code for me. please check my Question jquery and update your jquery. that will really appreciated

Comment: i am new with Ajax so difficult for me to update this code

Comment: Tell me, what does not work in my code? What is missing? So that I can fix it.

Comment: Please check my website [LINK](http://www.cbleu.net/sites/farooq/) Ajax not adding anything to, `id="post-cont"` in sidebar.

Comment: missing means something like that `var names = ['aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad'];` and `for (var i=0; i<names.length; i++)` these thing need to work for Ajax adding

Comment: I try but someting wrong in php function Please check at [Web Server](http://www.cbleu.net/sites/farooq/)

Comment: update php and js (edit  2)

Comment: update js (edit 3)

Comment: Last Thing---  As we get `post_title and post_thumb`  please edit function to get post_id with Ajax. And thanks for Help

Comment: update (edit 4)